# sql server 2008 print column names

Tags: javascript, sql-server-2008-r2

I am trying to print the column names of a table in **SQL Server 2008 r2**. the table has one column named `chardata`.
I used a select statement,

```
sqlQuery = "select * from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Test'" ;
println(data = db.select(sqlQuery));
```

but it just prints to the screen *[object,object]*.
How can I get the column name from this select statement?

Comment: What language are you using? PHP?

Comment: @jpw I am using javascript.

Comment: @jpw i'am trying to get the column names for formatting so I don't have to hardcode the column names when i do a select query on the table.

Comment: I think this is more of a javascript problem then a sql. I just need to put out properties from the object. sorry guys.

Comment: Indeed, inspect the data object and see what it holds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript code:

```
var connection = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Connection") ;
var connectionstring="Data Source=<server>;Initial Catalog=<catalog>;User ID=<user>;Password=<password>;Provider=SQLOLEDB";
connection.Open(connectionstring);
var rs = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
rs.Open("select COLUMN_NAME from information_schema.columns where table_name = 'Test'", connection);
rs.MoveFirst
while(!rs.eof)
{
   document.write(rs.fields(0));
   rs.movenext;
}
rs.close;
connection.close;
```

A better way to connect to Sql Server would be to use some server side language like PHP, Java, .NET among others. Client Javascript should be used only for the interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to put name in your table, you can use of 'AS' value end of line query
for example: (select T1.*)AS stude

Comment: i think the question is how do i pull out the name of the column out of the data object.

Comment: oh im sorry, yeah i thing alireza's answer is true